# Check for file existance and read permissions

Tags: c, file, permissions, stat

I am trying to check if my file specified by `file_path` exists and is readable. This is my code:

```
if (stat(file_path,&fileStat) > 0 && (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR))
{
    puts("SUCCESS");
    create_message(OK);
}
```

Can you detect a problem with the given code? Is the part `(fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR)`  correct?

Comment: `FILE *f = fopen(file_path, "rb"); if (f) { puts("SUCCESS"); create_message(OK); }` will avoid a [TOCTOU vulnerability](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html) if you're trying to actually read the specified file afterward (don't forget to close the file after you're done). If you're just checking for read permissions, then you're fine, except you might want to use `S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH` for generic read permissions rather than checking whether the file is readable by its owner (`S_IRUSR`) since you may not be the file owner (e.g. `/usr/bin/2to3` isn't a file you own).

Comment: Why are you trying to check if a file exists and is readable?  If it's so you can open it for reading, skip the check and **just open it for reading**.  Just because your checks tell you the file exists and your cursory permissions checks say you can read the file, that doesn't mean you can actually open the file for reading.  There are a *lot* of other permissions checks in place than just the file permission bits - ACLs and "extra" security checks such as those from SE Linux can stop you from reading the file. In general, checking X to see if you can do Y is a bad idea - X is not Y.

Comment: `stat()` returns 0 on success.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want stat() for this, you want access().

```
if (access(filename, R_OK)) {
    // code to handle missing or unreadable file
} else {
    // code to handle readable file
}
```

Your code would work if you changed the test on the return value of stat() as Jonathan Leffler points out, but Unix provides a system call to do precisely what you want, so you might as well use it.

But as other commenters have pointed out, if you are going to read this file, you would be better served to just open it for reading and let the open failure inform you of the problem.